# Creating vector of vector of complex numbers

Tags: c++, vector

I'm attempting to create a vector of vectors of complex numbers, however it will not work, previous research indicates that the following should work

```
vector <vector <complex<double> > test(1,vector<complex<double> >(3));
```

it does not
I can't figure out why and I am going crazy trying to figure out why, I get the following error
error: template argument 1 is invalid

Can anyone figure out why?

Answer (score 4):

You are missing one `>`:

```
vector<vector<complex<double> > > test(1, vector<complex<double> >(3));
                             // ^
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I didn't see that